# How/when is PhoneApp instantiated in android

Tags: android

I've read in a few places that PhoneApp (com.android.phone.PhoneApp.java), is a "persistent process" which is "started early in the boot sequence." Can anybody explain exactly how and when this happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question....
The following entry in the AndroidManifest.xml file instructs the ActivityManager to start the specified activity.

```
<!--  Broadcast Receiver that will process BOOT Complete and launch OTA 
  --> 
- <receiver android:name="OtaStartupReceiver" android:exported="false">
- <intent-filter android:priority="100">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```